# @BidingMethod is not applicable to method

Tags: android, data-binding

I am using `BindingMethod` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingMethod.html) like this

```
@BindingMethod(type = InputView.class, attribute = "android:title", method = "setTitle")
```

but it shows the error

[image]

How can I use `BindingMethod`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happened when I put the @BindingMethod inside the class.
So put it above the class

```
@BindingMethods({
        @BindingMethod(type = InputView.class, attribute = "app:title", method = "setTitle")
})
public class InputView extends LinearLayout {
   ...
}
```